# Flyout not showing for buttons inside ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml, windows

I am trying to show a Flyout whenever a user presses a button inside a listbox I have created. Here is the code used to load the bind the item source and attach the flyout.

```
            <myControls:myListbox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
                <myControls:myListbox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=MyField}"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Loaded="DeleteButton_OnLoaded" Click="OnDeleteConfirmationClick" Flyout="{StaticResource MyFlyout}" Grid.Column ="1""></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </myControls:myListbox.ItemTemplate>
            </myControls:myListbox>
```

Here is the code for the flyout static resource.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="MyFlyout">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Some confirmation message</TextBlock>
            <Button></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

I am receiving the `OnLoaded` event for every button however both the Click and Flyout are not being fired. Does this have to do with the buttons being inside an `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Throw `ClickMode="Press"` on your button.

Comment: @ChrisW. That did the trick! I guess the default mode of "Release" was never able to fire since the listbox would close. (Please mark as answer) :)

Comment: I think it's more to do with the listbox having its own click event for the selected item, so to click something like a Button inside a listbox item, that item has to be selected in order for you to be able to click that button.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an event based object like that in a template you need reach outside of its items events with the declaration of a [ClickMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) so in your instance for example adding `ClickMode="Press"` to your button will allow it to detach and handle its own events.

Since as it sits, you have to have the item selected that the button sits in in order for its click to get handled.

Not sure if that's the most technically sound explanation but the concept is correct, and glad you got your remedy. Cheers!